# How to solve using 2 versions of the same dll in the project?

Tags: wpf, clickonce, .net-assembly, gac

I'm using the log4net.dll in my project to register logs, and I'm also using some dlls from SAP that has log4net.dll as dependency.

The problem is that the SAP is using an older version of this dll and when I publish it using clickonce and the customer will install in his machine it says that the application requires the older version of the log4net in the GAC folder.

How can I put both versions on the customer GAC? I already tried some samples, but no success

Answer (score 1):

This is I believe what's called assembly aliasing

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx

UPDATE

Scope resolution is done via :: (more resemble C++ than C#). Good discussion is at 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ansonh/archive/2006/09/28/extern-alias-walkthrough.aspx